# Combobox selectedvalue is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls

I am working on a WPF project. I am having a ComboBox and I want to update its Selected value on a certain event. My Code is given below;

Here is my xaml code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSeverity" Height="23" 
  Margin="10,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedValuePath="Content">
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Low"/>
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Medium"/>
       <ComboBoxItem Content="High"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is my CS code

```
SomeEvent(){
cmbSeverity.SelectedValue = "High"; 
}
```

Kindly guide me

Answer (score 2):

You can use Databinding on the `SelectedItem` property, and bind it to a property. Such as:

In your XAML:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding MyProperty}"
```

In your code: (Preferably your ViewModel)

```
public class MyViewModel : INofityPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    { 
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myProperty = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared ItemsSource as collection of ComboBoxItems and trying to set selected value to string which won't work because ***ItemsSource collection type and selected value type should be same***.

So, change your declaration to this and it will work *(use string objects instead of comboBoxItems)*:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSeverity" Height="23" 
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            Margin="10,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <sys:String>Low</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Medium</sys:String>
    <sys:String>High</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```